# Code to end one batch file with another-can anyone assist?

Tags: file, batch-file, prepare

I have a small batch program i made to run a few batch files. I have it set up to run the files. Just a quick question:
I have a prep file to get the files ready for the next batch file. However, the prep file runs in a loop. I made it run in a loop so i could customize it per-machine. I want it to basically loop for 10 seconds and then close. I want it so my main batch file opens the prep batch file, runs it for 10 seconds, closes it, and then runs the next batch file in the sequence. Is there any way to do this? See the example below for more. Thanks!

Example:

```
Launcher folder/prep.bat
@echo off
start prep.bat
//Wait for 10 seconds, then close prep.bat
start launch.bat
```

Comment: `taskkill` will close the prep.bat and `ping -n 10 localhost > nul` will give you a ten second delay pretty much.  `Timeout` is available on later Windows.

Comment: @foxidrive Thanks for your help, but i do not understand how to use the taskkill. could you please explain some more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `prep.bat` add this

```
@Echo Off
title Prep.bat
```

and then in the controlling batch file add this

```
start "" prep.bat
ping -n 10 localhost >nul
taskkill /f /im cmd.exe /fi "windowtitle eq Prep.bat"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I love stack overflow. on a normal basis, i just log on and ask a question and in about 10 mins i have 3 or 4 helpful answers!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing quite what `prep.bat` does, or more why it needs to loop, advice may be way off mark.

Try this structure:

Main bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
DEL stopprep.txt 2>nul
START wprep.bat
timeout /t 10 >nul
ECHO.>stopprep.txt
:waitprep
IF EXIST stopprep.txt timeout /t 1 >nul& GOTO waitprep
ECHO prep now stopped
```

Wprep.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:loop
set /a delay=2+(%random% %% 7)
timeout /t %delay%
if not exist stopprep.txt goto loop
del stopprep.txt
EXIT
```

I called the batch `WPREP.bat` because I already had a `prep.bat` in my test directory.

The main batch uses `timeout` and suppresses its output using `>nul` After 10 seconds, it creates a flagfile `stopprep.txt` and then waits 1 sec repeatedly until the file disappears.

The subsidiary batch should pop up and show a countdown from 2..9 seconds, then repeat until the `STOPPREP.TXT` file appears - at least 10 secs after it was started. I deliberately chose not to suppress `timeout`'s output to have some activity visible in the window.

If your system doesn't have `TIMEOUT` installed, then `ping -n timeoutrequired+1 127.0.0.1 >nul` is likely to work, as may `choice` which has made a re-appearance in the standard distribution lately.

---

If the subsidary batch does not close, check that it ends with an `EXIT` statement. If it still does not close, try `CLS&EXIT`

Or, to terminate using TASKKILL:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
START wprep.bat
timeout /t 10 >nul
FOR /f "tokens=2" %%i IN ('tasklist/v^|fIND /i " - wprep.bat   " ' ) DO >NUL TASKKILL /pid %%i
ECHO prep now stopped
```

where `WPREP.bat` needs to be changed to suit your purpose.

Comment: Thanks! The timer counts down like you said it should, but the prep.bat does not close. I have been trying to use taskkill, but i dont think you can use it with .bat files. is there any way to have the main batch kill the prep.bat file?